# Disable compiler optimization for function or block of code?

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, obfuscation

I want to disable compiler optimization for a single function or block of code.
I'm in Visual studio 2019 Environment.

I try below:

```
__forceinline void InsertJunkCode() {

#pragma optimize("", off)

    .... Junk Code ....

#pragma optimize("", on)

}

...

int main() {

    ...

    InsertJunkCode();

    ...

}
```

```
...
Error: C2156   pragma must be outside function
...
```

Is there a way to disable optimization for a single function or block of code?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error tells you, to put the pragmas *outside* the function?

Comment: Modern optimizers work on whole functions at once, at *least*.  It seems MSVC doesn't support finer granularity, which isn't surprising.  So you could factor some code out into a separate function that you wrap with pragmas.  But what's your actual goal here, like what problem are you solving by disabling optimization selectively?  If it's benchmarking, that's not useful, use `volatile` or something to force a value to be materialized.  If you have buggy code that breaks with optimization, fix it!

Comment: I tried to put #pragma outside of the function. I checked PE file using IDA Pro, but Junk Code was optimized.

Comment: What is your function really doing? What is the actual and real and underlying problem you're trying to solve? What is this "junk code"? Please try to create a [mre] to show us. And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I want to protect my program from **cracker**. The idea is to protect the program to some extent. I Insert confusing code into my program. In short,**Junk Code** is rubbish code.

Comment: Using the ```volatile``` type qualifier forces the compiler to be strict about memory that has been used.

Comment: Do `volatile` type works on function? I know that it is meaningless for function. Am i wrong?

Comment: To be honest, that won't help. If someone wants to hack or crack your program, it will be done. Big companies have spend millions of dollars trying, and it just doesn't work.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/75nx384jc - pragmas outside `InsertJunkCode` works as expected for me, but of course it doesn't inline.  If someone reverse engineering your code doesn't see the function name, they might spend time tracing through what it does, but that'll be much easier (especially with a decompiler) because it's unoptimized, so each C statement corresponds to one block of asm, not mixed.  It will be immediately visible in the asm that this function is unoptimized.  Tracing all the loads and stores to the stack is a pain by hand, but a decompiler will do it for you.

Comment: @gloking: Iman is suggesting using `volatile` on some of the local variables of `InsertJunkCode` so you can write do-nothing code and not have it optimized away.

Comment: disabling optimization makes it even far more easier to reverse engineer. Obfuscators might help but obviously it just buys you a little bit more time before crackers find the way

Comment: Your intent may be to obfuscate, but your question is not about obfuscation, and should not be tagged thus.  You will attract viewers interested in second guessing your intent rather than answering your question.  Even if it is an X-Y question, it has narrow scope.

Comment: @gloking *I want to protect my program from **cracker**.*  [Good luck with that](https://ghidra-sre.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The optimise pragma works on whole functions only, not arbitrary code segments.  As such the pragma must appear outside of any function and applies to all functions defined between the on and the off.

```
#pragma optimize("", off)
__forceinline void InsertJunkCode() 
{
    .... Junk Code ....
}
#pragma optimize("", on)
```

This is clear from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize):

> The optimize pragma must appear outside a function. It takes effect at the first function defined after the pragma is seen.